# won't play video or give error

Tags: python, python-2.7, video, opencv

When I try to open and play a video, the code runs and finishes in 0.2 seconds, without any errors or playing the actual video. The code finishes without doing anything.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(r'C:\Users\Hayden\Desktop\test.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The only recommendation I've seen for this is to change the waitKey parameter to 1, but that doesn't make a difference right now.

I appreciate any and all help!

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you use os.startfile.
You have to import os then say I had a file in a directory path C:\Users\me\Videos
Then I would do,

`os.startfile('C:\Users\me\Videos')`. This is if you are on Windows, if you are not, 
don't include the 'C:\' in that. If you get a unicode error in the path, use double backslashes. 
`os.startfile('C:\\Users\\me\\Videos')`

Comment: If this is wrong please just add a comment and I will see why.

Comment: `r'C:\Users\Hayden\Desktop\test.mp4'` is valid similar to `'C:\\Users\\me\\Videos'`

Comment: Its the command I used that I changed. I used os.startfile and you used cv2. For os.startfile you do have to import os.